# Reading on SerialPort doesn't give me the expected result

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to read some data on the Serial Port but I doesn't have the same result between a Monitor Software (like 232 analyzer) and my program.

Here is what 232 analyzer reads:

```
001 003 001 102 000 004 165 234 
001 003 006 144 000 008 068 169 
001 003 005 000 000 042 196 217 
001 003 001 096 000 042 197 247 
001 003 001 096 000 042 197 247 
001 003 014 000 000 042 198 253
```

And here is what I read from SerialPort:

```
 001
 003 001 102 000 004 165 234
 001
 003 006 144 000 008 068 169
 001
 003 005 000
 000 042 196 217
 001
 003 001 096 000 042 197 247
 001
 003
 001 096 000 042 197 247
 001
 003 014 000 000 042 198 253
```

All my frames are just "truncated" and I don't find out why. 
The SerialPort is configured in `9600, n, 8, 1` in both programs.

How can I fix this and get the same frames that in 232 analyzer?

P.S:

I get frames like that (the ReadTimeout is set to 200ms):

```
while(true)
{
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = sp.Read(buff, 0, 1024);
    // ...
}
```

---

### EDIT

When doing an `Thread.Sleep(10);` before reading, I get:

```
 001
 003 001 102 000 004 165 234
 001
 003 006 144 000 008 068 169
 001
 003 005 000 000 042
 196 217
 001
 003 001 096 000 042 197 247
 001
 003 001 096 000
 042 197 247
 001
 003 014 000 000 042 198 253
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serial ports are completely undelimited so whenever you read, you read what is available. That might be 1 byte, 10 bytes, or 1024 bytes. Wait a little longer and you'll have more data, albeit of an entirely unpredictable size unless you only read a byte at a time.

The "monitor" software likely simply formats it into nice blocks for you.

Comment: [After your edit] And I wouldn't rely on a Sleep(10) sleeping for exactly 10ms and resulting in exactly a determinate number of bytes waiting for you. You've got a hardware serial port that buffers data, an OS that probably does some buffering, and then your program, all running simultaneously. Don't ever rely on OS timings to get a determinate number of bytes from the port. If it ain't ready to read, it won't have the data for you.

Comment: This Thread.Sleep(10) came from my comment and was prefixed by "Just for diagnosis" - it was never meant as a resolution

Answer (score 2):

IIRC the ReadTimeout is only honoured, if there is no data waiting, so whenever the first byte is already in the FIFO buffer, sp.Read() will return immediatly, giving whatever data is available.

Serial ports behave as a stream, not as a sequence of frames - any framing would have to come from the application.

Update after receiving feedback: Since framing comes from the application, you have to know your frame size. This might be encoded as part of the frame header, in which case reading byte by byte might be the best solution. If there is a fixed length frame (8 bytes in your example) you could use

```
while(true)
{
    byte[] frame = new byte[8];
    int read = 0;
    while (read<8)
    {
        sp.Read(frame, read, 8-read);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but what I don't understand is why 232 analyzer gives me the expected result (result I except) and my program not.

Comment: Most RS232 Analyzers use whitespace or newlines to denote a pause in the stream. When you communication partner sends framed data, this will cause inactivity time translated to newlines.
Just for diagnosis try a Thread.Sleep(10) before the sp.Read() - a frame of 8 Bytes should take a little less than that.

Comment: I edited my question with the result of adding the `Thread.Sleep(10);`. I'm alright with new lines but the stream I read isn't "new lined"...

Comment: If your frames are fixed length, use the update to my answer.

Comment: By "translated to newlines" I meant translated by the analyzer, not the app.